# Install pisa on Ubuntu (django)

Tags: ubuntu, installation, pisa

I'm trying to install pisa, I have all the requirements installed.

I try import:

```
import ho.pisa as pisa
```

or:

```
import xhtml2pd.pisa as pisa
```

Error:

```
ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named reportlab.lib.units
```

Last traceback:

```
from pisa_util import *

from reportlab.lib.units import inch, cm
```

I'm running in virtual environment. I believe i have all requirements installed.

I did:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pisa
```

created test.html, and in command-line:

```
xhtml2pdf test.html target.pdf
```

This generate pdf correctly

However:

```
pip install reportlab
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): reportlab in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Still throw error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you don't have reportlab installed.

Comment: thanks for response Slater. I have installed reportlab but same error. see my edit for what I tried.

Comment: see my edit once more, I install reportlab

Comment: thank you, I install reportlab in the virtual environment BIN directly, and it works now.

Comment: Virtualenv is an isolated Python environments, It creates an environment that has its own installation directories, that doesn’t share libraries with other virtualenv environments (and optionally doesn’t access the globally installed libraries either). So even though you install reportlab previously on your machine, your still need to do it in your virtualenv.

Comment: hi Nicholas, yes thanks, this is what I eventually figured out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>**This is the solution by the question's author, moved to the appropriate section.

To question's author: if you want to gain reputation, feel free to write a new answer, then ping me to remove this answer.**</sub>

Finally fixed the issue.

If you are in virtual environment, you must execute:

```
pip install reportlab
```

in the `bin` directory under `project` folder, i.e.:

```
~/.virtualenvs/project/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

pip install xhtml2pdf

pip install pisa